# Sharing on Twitter and Facebook via android app

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, sharing

I'm developing an adroid app with wich I can share text (and later pictures too) via facebook and twitter. I found some code which is opening the facebook/twitter sharing window but the text that needs to be shared is in an EditText in the app so my question is how can i insert my text from the EditText to te text that will be shared (sorry for the bad english if you need further explanation or you didn't understood anything then i will try too explain it better). This is my code for both sharing methods:

Facebook:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(
                    android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                    (String) v.getTag(R.string.app_name));
            shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    (String) v.getTag(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            PackageManager pm = v.getContext().getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                    shareIntent, 0);
            for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
                if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook")) {
                    final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
                    final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(
                            activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                            activity.name);
                    shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                    shareIntent.setComponent(name);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(shareIntent);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Twitter:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(
                    android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                    (String) v.getTag(R.string.app_name));
            shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    (String) v.getTag(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            PackageManager pm = v.getContext().getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
            for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
                if ("com.twitter.android.PostActivity"
                        .equals(app.activityInfo.name)) {
                    final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
                    final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(
                            activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                            activity.name);
                    shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                    shareIntent.setComponent(name);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(shareIntent);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this method to share photo with text. Call this method and pass argument nameofapp and imagepath. Name of app means like on which you want to share like gmail , facebook , twitter.

```
private void share(String nameApp, String imagePath,String text) {
try
{
    List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
    if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
        for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
                Intent targetedShare = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                targetedShare.setType("image/jpeg"); // put here your mime type
                if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(nameApp) || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(nameApp)) {
                    targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, text);
                    targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,text);
                    targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)) );
                    targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                    targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
                }
            }
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Select app to share");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
            startActivity(chooserIntent);
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
}
}
```

Use this for facebook :-

```
try {
File filePath = "/mnt/sdcard/vmphoto.jpg"; //This is imagefile path in your change it acc. to your requirement.
share("facebook",filePath.toString(),"Hello"); <<<<<Hello is text. send acc. to you req.

}
catch(Exception e) {
       //exception occur might your app like gmail , facebook etc not installed or not working correctly.
}
```

For twitter

```
try {
File filePath = "/mnt/sdcard/vmphoto.jpg"; //This is imagefile path in your change it acc. to your requirement.
share("twitter",filePath.toString(),"Hello"); <<<<<Hello is a text send acc. to you req.

}
catch(Exception e) {
       //exception occur might your app like gmail , facebook etc not installed or not working correctly.
}
```

Comment: thx for the help but i still don't know how to copy the text from my EditText to the text which gonna be shared ... the purpose of the app is to make your life easier, that you want to share somthing you write your text in the EditText and you choose a photo from your phone and with a simple click on a button you share it on fb/twitter etc that's why i need to copy the text from my EditText to the text that will be shared ... if you could help me with this i would appreciate ...

Comment: First get the string entered in edittext and uri of image and pass this argument in above method. Ex to get text from edittext  Strin userid = editTextUserId.getText().toString();

Comment: i tried with a simple share ("facebook",path,"TEST") .... the image is uploaded in my album but no text is asociated with it ... and the File filePath = "/mnt/sdcard/vmphoto.jpg"; isn't working only if i use String filePath = "/mnt/sdcard/vmphoto.jpg";

Comment: One important thing in facebook photo will upload on your account but text will not using this intent. and on twitter and gmail you can send image + text.

Answer (score 2):

For attaching image on gmail,facebook,twitter with text use below code.

```
File filePath = context.getFileStreamPath("vmphoto.jpg");
share("gmail",filePath.toString());
share("facebook",filePath.toString());
share("twitter",filePath.toString());
```

// code of share(String nameApp,String imagePath) function

```
  void share(String nameApp, String imagePath) {
 try
{
  List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
  Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");
  List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
  if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
    for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
        Intent targetedShare = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        targetedShare.setType("image/jpeg"); // put here your mime type
        if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(nameApp) || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(nameApp)) {
            targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sample Photo");
         targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"This photo is created by App Name");
            targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)) );
            targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
            targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
        }
    }
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Select app to share");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivity(chooserIntent);
  }
  }

       catch(Exception e){
      Log.v("VM","Exception while sending image on" + nameApp + " "+  e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can I share an image with a URL without having to download it to the SD Card?

Comment: yes but one condition you should have twitter , Facebook app in your mobile phone .

Comment: I have the twitter app installed. But I cannot find a solution on internet that would allow me to share image on Twitter with image URL instead of from SD Card.