# Android share Intent share image doesn't exist

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to share an image file which saved to internal storage using share intent.
after I intent image file doesn't display.

I used following code to save the image file

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("twitterimage.jpg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Writing the bitmap to the output stream
    bikeBm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("saveToInternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
}
```

//intent code

```
File internalFile = getFileStreamPath("twitterimage.jpg");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(internalFile);

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,new File(uri));
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));
```

when I check the file existance using above "uri", the image file exists
in the internal storage but checking the file using

```
String file = "data/data/com.bike.app/twitterimage.jpg";
File f = new File(file);
```

shows me the file not exist.

pls help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917495/sharing-on-twitter-and-facebook-via-android-app/13917710#13917710

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i am gessing right you want to share images between to applications. Your probleme is that you used `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` when you write a file so other applications cannot have access to this file.

To share an image you can use [MediaProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) to restrict access to you Media or simply used `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE` but the file will be public readable then.

hope that help

Comment: thank you for the reply.I tried with Context.MODE_PUBLIC but it's doesn't exist.so I used MODE_WORLD_READABLE to save the image and then got worked!thanx you gave me the hint.